Default avatar doesn't show up in my django-project profile
I tried to load a default avatar image in my profile page but it doesn't show up. However, new avatar photos actually does.  Explain me, what did i worng?
HTML template of profile page:
{% extends 'movieapp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Данные пользователя</h1>
<form  method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user.photo %}
         <p><img src="{{ user.photo.url }}">
    {% else %}
         <img src="{% static 'default_image' %}">
    {% endif %}
    {% for f in form %}
    <p><label class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{ f.label }}</label>{{ f }}</p>
    <div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><button type="submit">Отправить</button></p>

</form>

<hr>
<p><a href="{% url 'password_change'%}">Сменить пароль</a></p>
{% endblock %}

forms.py:
class ProfileUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(disabled='Логин', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}))
    email = forms.CharField(disabled='E-mail', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}))
    this_year = datetime.date.today().year
    date_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=tuple(range(this_year - 100, this_year - 5))))
    class Meta:
        model=get_user_model()
        fields=['photo','username','email','date_of_birth','first_name','last_name',]
        labels={
            'first_name':'Имя',
            'last_name':'Фамилия',

        }
        widgets={
            'fist_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'})
        }

models.py:
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    photo=models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d/',blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='Фото')
    date_of_birth=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name='Дата рождения')


views.py:
class ProfileUser(UpdateView):
model=get_user_model()
form_class = ProfileUserForm
template_name = 'user/profile.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy("profile_changed.html")
extra_context = {'title': 'Профиль пользователя',
                 'default_image':settings.DEFAULT_USER_IMAGE}

settings.py:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/users/'
DEFAULT_USER_IMAGE = MEDIA_URL + 'profile/chad.jpg'

urls of the project:
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('movieapp.urls')),
path("__debug__/", include("debug_toolbar.urls",namespace='users')),
path("users/", include("users.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

The directory of default avatar image:


In your view class you already passing default_photo variable. So in your template, you should use {{ default_photo }}, not {% static 'default_image' %}.
Actually I think, the issue is in the view class. You are not sending the extra context. Try this:
class ProfileUser(UpdateView):
    model = get_user_model()
    form_class = ProfileUserForm
    template_name = 'user/profile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("profile_changed.html")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['default_image'] = settings.DEFAULT_USER_IMAGE
        return context


It didn't work. Default pic still doesn't show up

Can you please check what is the url using inspect view in browser? this may give some hint.

Check my solution above, updated.
